# Loopback join relation without selecting relation

Tags: orm, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

I'am trying to build a query with loopback 4 with relation between 2 entities

customer.model.ts:

```
@model()
export class Customer extends Entity {
  // id, name properties
  @hasMany(() => Order)
  orders?: Order[];
}
```

order.model.ts:

```
@model()
export class Order extends Entity {
  // id, desc properties
  @belongsTo(() => Customer)
  customerId: Customer;
}
```

My goal is to get all cutomers that have at least 1 order **but without selecting their orders**, this my query

```
    await customerRepository.find({ 
       include: [{ relation: "orders" }],
   });
```

I tried too :

```
    await customerRepository.find({ 
       include: [{ relation: "orders" }],
       fields: {propertyName:  }
   });
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of excluding entries that doesn't have any related data (in your case excluding customers without any orders) is possible using INNER JOIN, which currently [isn't supported in loopback](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/issues/5132) by default.

You can use this newly published sequelize extension I recently worked on called
[loopback4-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback4-sequelize) which supports [inner joins](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-sequelize#inner-join) as well.

To achieve the expected results you'll need to set `required` to `true` as described [here](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-sequelize#inner-join), so your filter object will look like this:

```json
{
  "include": [{
    "relation": "orders",
    "required": true, // returns only those customers who have orders
    "scope": {
      "fields": [] // exclude all fields in orders
    }
  }]
}
```

A point to keep in mind is that loopback by default **never** run SQL JOIN Queries internally. It uses inclusion resolvers which is responsible to include related models and is called after your source table's data is returned. Resulting in two different calls when you use `include` in your filter object.